# How to enable interworking between aarch64 and aarch32 in gem5 simulator

Tags: 32bit-64bit, gem5, armv8

I am running simulations with armv8 processor model in gem5, and want to run both 64 bit and 32 bit codes in my simulation. However, I found that current gem5 implementation does not seem to support the interworking.

> **Pertinent Non-supported Features**
>   Currently in ARMv8-A implementation in gem5, there isn't support for interworking between AArch32 and AArch64 execution. This limits the ability to run some OSes that expect to execute both 32-bit and 64-bit code, but is expected to be fixed in the short term. Additionally, there has been limited testing of EL2 and EL3 modes in the implementation.

Because it passed a decent amount of time since the document got updated, I am curious whether someone already enabled the interworking feature so that her simulation could switch between aarch64 and aarch32 codes within one simulation. Could you help me finding out previous efforts (e.g. arm-dev branch) to enable the interworking if you know any? I also want to get your consultation on where I can start with to support the interworking by myself in case where no one ever tried it. Thank you for your comment in advance.

Comment: I *think* this is supposed to work now. Unfortunately it is hard to say given that documentation does not provide a precise test case... http://gem5.org/ARM_Implementation There is one known floating point bug when task switching between multiple floating point applications which we are working on, I'll try to remember to ping this thread when a patch is pushed. So my advice for now is: give it a shot right now to see if your use case is working, and if not send a precise bug report.